# Adding extra fields to MongoDB result efficiently

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

For an API, I am returning a list of objects from my MongoDB. To be more RESTful, I would like to add a field `link` to every object. My approach is to calculate it when processing the request and add the link of each object in a simple loop:

```
exports.list = function (req, res) {
  collection.find({}, {fields: {a: 1, b: 1, c: 1}, function (err, docs) {
    for (var i = 0; i < docs.length; i++) {
      docs[i].link = 'http://api.example.com/fooobject/' + docs[i]._id;
    }
    res.send(docs);
  });
};
```

However, I have the feeling that this way of doing it might not be very performant. Are there any better ways? For example, telling MongoDB directly to do such kind of calculation?

Or is it even recommended to save the full link in the database itself?

Comment: There is no way to ask mongo to do this calculations. You can skip them on the server side and only do them on the client when you parse results, you got from server.

Comment: What's your actual use case? "Being more RESTful" doesn't really make sense, in and of itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to "re-shape" your documents in this way you can use the [**`.aggregate()`**](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#aggregate) method instead of find:

```js
collection.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "a": 1,
        "b": 1,
        "c": 1,
        "link": { "$concat": [
            "http://api.example.com/fooobject/",
            "$_id"
        ]}
     }}
],function(err,result) {

   // Output work here
})
```

This uses [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) to "shape" your document response by selecting and creating fields. In this case there is the use of [**`$concat`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concat/) in order to join the string with the value of the `_id` field.

To add query information to your search, see the [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) operator.

For other uses, see the reference for [aggregation framework operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/).